# Why is public properties of Class visible but not it's public methods in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF window in a project in the same solution as a WCF project. In the WCF project I have a public Class with public properties and public methods.

```
public class TemporaryExam
{
    public Exam Exam { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public List<PossibleAnswer> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }


    public void AddQuestion(Question question)
    {
        Questions.Add(question);
    }

    public void AddPossibleAnswer(PossibleAnswer possibleAnswer)
    {
        PossibleAnswers.Add(possibleAnswer);
    }
}
```

In the window codebehind I can assign values to the properties but get an error saying that TemporaryExam does not contain definition for AddQuestion(question).

```
TemporaryExam temporaryExam = new TemporaryExam();
Exam exam = new Exam { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Title = "Exam3" };
Question question = new Question
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    ExamQuestion = "Vad heter du?",
    ExamId_Id = exam.Id
};
PossibleAnswer possibleAnswer = new PossibleAnswer
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    PossibleAnswer1 = "Bamse",
    QuestionId_Id = question.Id
};

temporaryExam.AddQuestion(question);
```

How come the properties are visible but not the methods?

**Edit:** 
This generates no erros:

```
temporaryExam.Exam = exam;
```

Comment: @Clemens tried this temporaryExam.Exam = exam; and it works but the methods are still not accessible :/

Comment: Sounds like the WCF project isn't up-to-date. Make sure it's building properly and the reference to it in the WPF project is referencing the actual build and not a stale copy.

Comment: @Cameron I published the WCF project again and updated the service reference in the WPF project but still gets the same error. The TemporaryExam Class is a seperate file in the WCF project does that matter?

Comment: If you're writing business logic code (e.g., creating a TemporaryExam) in your codebehind you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try removinig typed arguments (Question) from the method as you may need to define the custom types to expose from WCF projects.